# Conan version installed with pip

Tags: pip, conan

As conan documentation describes, the recommended way to install conan is using pip: https://conan.io/downloads.html. If I do so, I get conan v 1.41. However on the official conan repo I see recipes created for conan >= 1.47, for example OpenSSL recipe file contains `required_conan_version = ">=1.47.0"`
How do I get the latest conan version?

Comment: Need to update to the latest version. You can do it by running `pip install -U conan`.  The `-U` argument tells to pip to upgrade the conan package to the latest version available on pypi.org

Comment: Thanks! But why pip install doesn't install the latest version?

Comment: Please report your OS, your Python version (2.7 support removed), your ``pip`` version.

Comment: Python 3.10, latest pip and it works the same way both on Win 10 and Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: It didn't install the latest because you have Conan installed already at some point. Pip always installs the latest version if you don't say which version you want. In case you have it already installed, it does not update automatically, you have to pass `-U`, otherwise it will do nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me it automatically installs a far newer version:

```
jenkins@fmdev04:/data/jenkins_home/workspace$ pip install conan
Collecting conan
  Downloading conan-1.58.0.tar.gz (779 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 779 kB 8.7 MB/s
```

You may want to try updating pip and Python on the computer.

You may also try:

```
pip install --force-reinstall -v "conan==1.47.0"
```